# Flutter Datatable

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi It is possible to create a flutter screen where the table is shown after filtering by dates an api?
I want to show after select a range of dates and tap the search button.

[image]

Comment: you can initially make the table invisible,after selecting the date range you can fetch the data & show the table.

Comment: Oh its posible? I tried but I failed im gonna do it again

Answer (score 0):

Create a table inside `Visible()` with a boolean property `_isVisible`. Make `_isVisible` true after clicked on Search button. Fetch data between given Initial Date and End Date by using you API and bind it into table.